# ffmpeg php exec not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec, flv, wmv

- I have ffmpeg installed
- safe_mode is off
- when i do this: `$movie = new ffmpeg_movie('Bear.wmv');` 
  I can use getDuration(), getFilename().... wthout any problems, so it's all seems to be working
- exec is working fine, cos when i do: `$output = exec('ls -lart');` I get a nice little result.

but when I do this:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i Bear.wmv outputfile.flv')
```

nothing happens

if I add: `$command_output, $result`
the only result i guess is: `array { }`

I have tried everything I could think of:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i Bear.wmv outputfile.flv')

exec('ffmpeg.so -i Bear.wmv outputfile.flv')

exec('/usr/lib/php5/20090626/ffmpeg -i Bear.wmv outputfile.flv')
```

I've tried all sizes and folders and codecs but still don't get anything back

All i wanna do is convert that video, Bear.wmv to an flv file.

I'm very close to crying like a baby and/or jumping out of the window (im only on the first floor but still lol)
so Please help!!??!

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG is a application wich don't output to STDIO but STDERR, so you can redirect it to standard output:

```
$cmd = $FFMPEGDIR . " -i somefile.avi 2>&1"; // SEE 2>&1 !!
```

Extracting size:

```
 exec( $cmd , $info );

      echo "<pre>".print_r($info,true)."</pre>";
      $resolution = preg_match( '@[ ,\t]([0-9]{3,4}x[0-9]{3,4})[ ,\t]@si' , implode( " " , $info ) , $durmatches );

      $rtab = explode( "x" , $durmatches[1] );

      $videowidth = $rtab[0];
      $videoheight = $rtab[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently set ffmpeg up for audio stuff... it's a bit of a black art, ffmpeg is notorious for not playing nice (or consistently) - what works (worked) for me might not work for you!

try using: shell_exec()

or:

```
$command="{$FFMPEG_BINARY} ... rest of your options";
$process=proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes);
if (!$process)
{
    // failed to exec...
}
else
{
    // command ran...
}
```

my ffmpeg was in... "/usr/bin/ffmpeg" just check you've got right path too.